# Найти папку .git

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitg

Начал изучать git и в терминале все работает. на `git init` получаю

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/khaljava/scrapper/.git/
```

установил [gitg](https://github.com/GNOME/gitg), который требует `.git/` а в папке такого файла нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.git/` - это не файл, а папка.

Она появляется после инициализации или клона репозитория.

Comment: git init без названия, поэтому не создавалась папка

Comment: @qm69: название тут не играет роли, папка создается всегда.

Answer (score 2):

`git init` создаёт репозиторий git в текущем каталоге. При этом создаётся его директория ".git" .

Все файлы и директории в линуксе, начинающиеся с "." - скрытые, увидеть их можно, например, набрав `ls -la` в консоли.

Answer (score 1):

для nautilus применимо "Ctrl+H" или "Вид -> Показать скрытые файлы"